# JQuery .validate triggered first on the second submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, jquery-validate

I am trying to validate a form. The form is dynamically generated and added to div on the page. When submitting the form I want the validation to be performed at once. What happens now is that the first time I submit the form is posted without being validated. The second time I hit submit it's validate.

Here is my script:

```
$("#registerform").live("submit", function(e){
                        //Prevent the form from submitting normally
                        e.preventDefault();
                       $("#registerform").validate({ 
                            rules: { 
                              firstname: "required",// simple rule, converted to {required:true} 
                              surname: "required",
                              //phonenumber: "required",
                              address: "required",
                             // address2: "required",
                              zipcode: "required",
                              username_ID: "required",
                              city: "required",
                              companyname: "required",
                              email: {// compound rule 
                              required: true, 
                              email: true 
                            }              
                            }, 
                            messages: { 
                              firstname: "Förnamn saknas" ,
                              surname: "Efternamn saknas",
                              address: "Adress saknas",
                             // address2: "required",
                              zipcode: "Postkod saknas",
                              username_ID: "Användarnamn saknas",
                              city: "Ort saknas",
                              companyname: "Företagsnamn saknas",
                              email: "Korrekt emailadress saknas"                             
                            } 
                          }); 
                        //alert("e");
                    $.post("registeraccount.php",$(this).serialize(),function(msg){
                    //alert the response from the server
                    //alert(msg);
            });
    });
```

My form:

```
<form id='registerform' action='registeraccount.php' method='post'> 
            Ägare av konto</br>
            * Förnamn: <input type='text' name='firstname' /> <br/>
            * Efternamn: <input type='text' name='surname' /> <br/>
            * Email: <input type='text' name='email' /> <br/>
            * Telefon: <input type='text' name='phonenumber' /> <br/>
            Företagsinformation: </br>
            * Adress: <input type='text' name='address' /> <br/>
            Adress: <input type='text' name='address2' /> <br/>
            * Postnummer: <input type='text' name='zipcode' /> <br/>
            * Ort: <input type='text' name='city' /> <br/>

            <br/>
            Kontoinformation</br> 
            <div id='username_message'></div>
            * Användarnamn: <input id='username_ID' type='text' name='username' />

            <br/>
            Företagsinformation<br/>
            * Företagsnamn (som kunden kommer se det): <input type='text' name='companyname' /> <br/>
            Organisationsnummer: <input type='text' name='organisationnumber' /><br/>
            <input id='submitaccountregistration' type='submit' value='Submit Comment' /> 
        </form>
```

How come it's not triggered on the first submit and how can I get the validation to be performed the first time I hit submit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At first submit event you are not validating form, but just attaching validator plugin to it. At second submit you are validating it and attaching validation again.

Just define function which adds your validation (function attachValidate(form) { $(form).validate... }) and run this function when form is generated/loaded.

Comment: nicksoft plz  help it out

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but i think you should call

```
$("#registerform").validate({ 
                            rules: { 
                              firstname: "required",// simple rule, converted to {required:true} 
                              surname: "required",
                              //phonenumber: "required",
                              address: "required",
                             // address2: "required",
                              zipcode: "required",
                              username_ID: "required",
                              city: "required",
                              companyname: "required",
                              email: {// compound rule 
                              required: true, 
                              email: true 
                            }              
                            }, 
                            messages: { 
                              firstname: "Förnamn saknas" ,
                              surname: "Efternamn saknas",
                              address: "Adress saknas",
                             // address2: "required",
                              zipcode: "Postkod saknas",
                              username_ID: "Användarnamn saknas",
                              city: "Ort saknas",
                              companyname: "Företagsnamn saknas",
                              email: "Korrekt emailadress saknas"                             
                            } 
                          });
```

outside of the click function (of course put it after you added the form to the DOM) so that you attach validation to the form before it's submitted. In your case it seems that the first time you click you set up the validation, which takes effects the second time you click.

Comment: How do I make sure I add it after the DOM and before I submit?

Answer (score 0):

did you using "pjax", if so you have to place validation code at "pjax:end" block

```
<script>
$(document).on('pjax:end', function () {
   $('#csv_form').validate();
});
</script>
```